# How did Richard get a [red] black eye at the end of Knives Out?

Tags: knives-out

The closing scene of Knives out takes place in the driveway in front of the Thrombley house.  During this scene, we notice that Richard now has a red patch surrounding his left eye.  In the previous scene, just moments before, Richard did not have a red patch.

My assumption is that Linda, who had just read Harlan's last note to her, was enraged to learn of Richard's infidelity, and had struck him, either by slap or fist.

Is this the likely explanation, or did I miss something?

Comment: I have had the same understanding of this scene.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got it, from [IMDB.com](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8946378/trivia?item=tr4868226)...

> At the epilogue, Linda Thrombey finally manages to decrypt the message Harlan left her, exposing the affair of her husband Richard, and stares at him dejectedly. Shortly after, in the very last scene, Richard is seen sporting a black left eye, implying that Linda is the one who caused it.